# What will happen to shared DLC if I buy Just Cause 3?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing, just-cause-3

My friend has shared his Steam library with me so I can play his games when he is not playing. He has Just Cause 3 with some DLC which I can play as i have made some progress in the Sky Fortress DLC.

If I buy Just Cause 3 for myself, what will happen to the DLC he purchased and shared with me? Will I still be able to play it?

Answer (score 4):

If both of you have the game and only one has the DLC, the DLC is not shared.

He keeps the DLC and you have to buy it for yourself.

From Steam family sharing FAQ: http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing?l=english

**Who owns and can access the DLC and in-game content associated with a shared title?**
A guest will have access to the lender's DLC, but only if the guest doesn't also own the base game. Guests may not purchase DLC for a base game they don't own. Any player may purchase, trade, earn, or otherwise acquire in-game content while playing a game, but in-game items cannot be shared between accounts. These items remain the property of the account that purchased or acquired them, whether borrowing or lending the base game.

Comment: Beat me to it. :)

Comment: if i buy JC3 and load up the game, what will happen to the dlc in-game, like the barvarium jetpack?

Comment: @Titanmaster970 edited the post, may that answer your question?